# Excel formula calculation using OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have scenario where I have to prepare two batch of excel files. I have two templates. I am automating a process. The 1st Excel file has formulas in it. I populate data using C# winform and OpenXML library in the first excel file. I want to have the formulas calculate results and then grab them to populate the 2nd excel file. I have tried various methods but was unsuccessful. I did use the following code hoping it will make the excel file calculate the formulas in it.

```
SpreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.ForceFullCalculation = true;
SpreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.FullCalculationOnLoad = true;
```

So basically the process should be

1. Make copy of the 1st excel file and populate it with data [This part is working]
2. Some how make the 1st excel file data calculate the formulas [This is the step I have problem with]
3. Copy the formula results values to the 2nd excel file [This part is working but as formula is not calculated the values are not being copied over]

I am reluctant to use excel interlop library as closing the excel does not work as well.

Comment: You'll be far better off with ClosedXML: https://closedxml.codeplex.com/

Comment: I did try with ClosedXML. I agree closedXML is very easy to use. But it does not make the excel calculate formulas also.

Comment: I see.  That's good to know.  We've always used it for data extracts and never really had to deal with formulas.  I guess it makes sense that I didn't know that it doesn't support formulas.